# Cannot Run JxBrowser Java Application on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, chromium, jxbrowser

I have created a Java swing application with an embedded Jx Browser for displaying html and JavaScript pages in application.
The application is build in windows environment using Net beans IDE 8.0, but when i try to run it on Ubuntu using command

> java -jar demo.jar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJs9t.png)
i get an error

> "Failed to extract chromium binaries in
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0............"

I have already checked that all the jxbrowser libraries a propely imported, it runs successfully​ on windows, i think it can be the problem of permission to /temp directory, so i tried to give permission to my demo.jar file from properties in ubuntu but no luck.

The Java app contains only single main class with following code copied from JxBrowser quick start guide

```
package pkgtry;

import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Try {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(browserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

I can't figure out whats the problem, please anyone help me out !

jxbrowser-browser.log

> Jun 12, 2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.Environment traceEnvironment
>   INFO: OS name: Linux Jun 12, 2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.Environment traceEnvironment
>   INFO: OS version: 4.10.0-19-generic Jun 12, 2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.Environment traceEnvironment
>   INFO: JRE version: 1.8.0_131 64-bit Jun 12, 2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.Environment traceEnvironment
>   INFO: JxBrowser version: 6.14.1 Jun 12, 2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.Environment traceEnvironment
>   INFO: User temp dir: /tmp Jun 12, 2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary INFO: Chromium binaries dir:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1 Jun 12, 2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary INFO: Analyzing Chromium binaries
>   dir... Jun 12, 2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE: The directory doesn't have
>   the following files: Jun 12, 2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/he.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/sv.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/mr.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/sk.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/da.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/uk.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/fa.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/zh-TW.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/kn.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/chrome_100_percent.pak Jun
>   12, 2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/icudtl.dat Jun 12, 2017
>   4:15:47 PM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/libjxbrowser-chromium64.so
>   Jun 12, 2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/gu.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/sr.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/vi.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/ja.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/nl.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/te.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/am.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/pl.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/en-US.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/jxbrowser-chromium64 Jun
>   12, 2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/ta.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/et.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/bg.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/th.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/resources.pak Jun 12, 2017
>   4:15:47 PM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/it.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/lv.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/fr.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/ro.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/hr.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/bn.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/fil.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/pt-PT.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/ca.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/libjxbrowser-common64.so
>   Jun 12, 2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/el.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/snapshot_blob.bin Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/cs.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/es.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/hu.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/tr.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/en-GB.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/ml.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/es-419.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/sw.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/ms.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/sl.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/zh-CN.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/ru.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/natives_blob.bin Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/id.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/ko.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/ar.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/pt-BR.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/fi.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/hi.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/nb.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/de.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary FINE:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/locales/lt.pak Jun 12,
>   2017 4:15:47 PM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.b run INFO:
>   Extracting Chromium binaries to
>   '/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1'... Jun 12, 2017 4:15:47
>   PM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.XZExtractor a INFO: The
>   '/chromium-linux64.7z' JAR resource URL is
>   jar:file:/home/akb/Documents/try/dist/lib/jxbrowser-linux64-6.14.1.jar!/chromium-linux64.7z
>   Jun 12, 2017 4:15:47 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.XZExtractor a INFO: The
>   '/7zr-linux' JAR resource URL is
>   jar:file:/home/akb/Documents/try/dist/lib/jxbrowser-linux32-6.14.1.jar!/7zr-linux
>   Jun 12, 2017 4:15:54 PM
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor
>   extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary SEVERE: Failed to extract Chromium
>   binaries into /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/7zr-linux": error=2, No
>   such file or directory    at
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.XZExtractor.extract(SourceFile:45)
>     at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.b.run(SourceFile:1067)   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor.extractChromiumBinariesIfNecessary(SourceFile:61)
>     at
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.(SourceFile:78)
>     at
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.create(SourceFile:51)
>     at
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC$a.(SourceFile:41)
>     at
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.getDefault(SourceFile:45)
>     at
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserContext.(SourceFile:63)
>     at
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserContext.(SourceFile:25)
>     at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.(SourceFile:139)    at
>   pkgtry.Try.main(Try.java:29) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot
>   run program "/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.1/7zr-linux":
>   error=2, No such file or directory    at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)  at
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.XZExtractor.extract(SourceFile:2018)
>     ... 11 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or
>   directory     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:247)    at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)  ... 15 more

Other Files jxbrowser-chromium.log, jxbrowser-ipc.log are empty

Comment: Please read [mcve]. How are we supposed to know what your application does?

Comment: It seems the binary files cannot be extracted to the temp directory. Could you please enable logging as described in the [Documentation](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/solution/articles/9000013125-logging) and provide me with the log messages.

Also, to check whether it's an issue with permissions, you can try to configure JxBrowser to extract the binary files into another directory using the "jxbrowser.chromium.dir" System Property.

Comment: @ArtemTrofimov i don't know how to use 'jxbrowser.chromium.dir' property it shows error, do i need to import any library to use it. Can you please give example how to state directory in this property

Comment: @ArtemTrofimov i have created the log files as you asked, how do i send it to you ?

Comment: @AakashBhadana please update your post with the log messages

Comment: @Vladimir Did it

Comment: @AakashBhadana, System Properties can be passed as VM parameters, for example `-Djxbrowser.chromium.dir="path-to-binaries"`. Also, you can set it directly in the code before creating the first Browser instance: `System.setProperty("jxbrowser.chromium.dir", "path-to-binaries");` Please try to extract binaries into a different directory and check whether it helps.

Comment: @ArtemTrofimov I tried extracting binaries in Documents folder, but still it is unable to extract binaries

Comment: @ArtemTrofimov what should i do, please help

Comment: @AakashBhadana, JxBrowser extracts an archive with binary files and 7zr utility from the JAR file resources. Then it runs 7zr utility to extract the binaries from the archive. The exception says that the utility file is not found, however, there were no exceptions during extraction. It looks like the utility file was removed right after extraction.

Comment: @AakashBhadana, The extraction mechanism was changed in JxBrowser 6.14.1, the previous versions used Java algorithm implementation to extract the binaries. Could you please try the previous [JxBrowser 6.14 version](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/discussions/topics/9000030255) and check whether the issue is reproducible.

Comment: @ArtemTrofimov Thanks !!! Version 6.14 worked without any problem, Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JFYI: It works with JxBrowser 6.14 version.